# how to skip particular character(s) in SQL LIKE query

Tags: sql

I have a table(say users) in which there is a column say name.

you may think table structure a shown below:

```
-------------
name
--------------
Abdul Khalid
--------------
Abdul, Khalid
--------------
Abdul - Khalid
--------------
other names
```

My question is can I do some query to find all the 3 rows in which the name column value is "Abdul Khalid"(basically "Abdul Khalid" or "Abdul, Khalid" or "Abdul - Khalid" if I skip  the "," and "-" character).

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `like`:

```
select t.*
from t
where name like 'Abdul%Khalid';
```

If you want the names anywhere in the string (but in that order), then put wildcards at the beginning:

```
select t.*
from t
where name like '%Abdul%Khalid%';
```

If you are passing in the value as a variable:

```
select t.*
from t
where name like replace('Abdul Khalid', ' ', '%');
```

Comment: Your query also match 'Abdul <any smybol> Khalid'

Answer (score 1):

For PostgreSQL is better to use '~'

```
 name ~ '^Abdul[ ,-]Khalid$'
```

OR if you want also in middle of string:

```
name ~ 'Abdul[ ,-]Khalid'
```

Or you can use translate (with index on it) for any SQL:

```
translate(name, ' ,-') = 'AbdulKhalid'
```

Answer (score 0):

you also can use REGEXP like this:

```
SELECT * from yourTable where name REGEXP 'Abdul( |, | - )Khalid';
```